# Grails error when attempting to divide variables in GSP

Tags: grails, gsp

I have a page where I'm trying to divide two variables and set the result to a new variable. I can add, subtract, and multiply them, but if I try and divide them I get an error saying "Division undefined."

I'm taking existing variables (totalProgressGoal and totalPrincGoal), fetching values from the db, and then adding them to the variables.

```
<g:set var="gain01" value="${pdd?.dataValue}" />
<g:set var="goal01" value="${pdd?.groupGoal.goalValue}" />
<g:set var="totalProgressGoal" value="${totalProgressGoal + gain01}" />
<g:set var="totalPrincGoal" value="${totalPrincGoal + goal01}" />
```

If I try and take the updated variables and divide them, then I get the error.

```
<g:set var="goalSuccessRatio" value="${totalProgressGoal / totalPrincGoal}"/>
```

Replacing the "/" with any other operator works, and if I set totalProgressGoal and totalPrincGoal with numeric values it works. What do I need to do to divide these values?

Clarification: The variables are set above as integers:

```
<g:set var="totalProgressGoal" value="${0}" />
<g:set var="totalPrincGoal" value="${0}" />
```

Comment: What are the classes for the two variables? Are they `Long`, `String`, `int`, what?

Comment: `int` or `Integer`? You really need to examine that. The problem is that one of them isn't a math class that you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect these variables are not actually of type `Integer` as you claim. Does casting them to an `Integer` work, e.g.

```
<g:set var="goalSuccessRatio" 
       value="${(Integer) totalProgressGoal / (Integer) totalPrincGoal}"/>
```

Comment: I think you're right about the variables, that is what Joshua suggested above as well. I tried your suggestion though, and I still get the same error.